# How do I fix my .woff webfonts to show on our website?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I have added Webfonts (.woff) to my site but they aren't showing up. My CCS code is below and I am trying to load it on https://electratherm.com/ in all headings and the navigation menu. I have used it in quotes, out of quotes but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
/* FONTS */

@font-face {
    font-family: "diwa";
    src: url("https://electratherm.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/fontsfonts/AFDiwa.WOFF") format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "diwa";
    src: url("https://electratherm.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/fontsfonts/AFDiwa-Bold.WOFF") format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "diwa";
    src: url("https://electratherm.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/fontsfonts/AFDiwa-BoldItalic.WOFF") format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "diwa";
    src: url("https://electratherm.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/fontsfonts/AFDiwa-Italic.WOFF") format('woff');
    font-style: italic;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
     font-family: "diwa", Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
}

.ush_menu_1 {
    font-family: "diwa", Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

I have cleared my browser cache and the CDN cache, This is what AFDiwa looks like: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fw-acme/af-diwa/

Comment: If you look in the console when you hit your site you can see this message: **https://electratherm.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza-child/fontsfonts/AFDiwa.WOFF net::ERR_ABORTED 404**. Thats a 404 not found error... check your path and that the file does exist on the server

Comment: Thank You! I knew it had to be something simple that I was missing.